# AltBeacon Library Scanning in BoundService does not stop on unbind() - Android O

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon

I am trying to scan for a Beacon and then once I have found it start Advertising a GATT Server from my phone. The problem is that the scan doesn't seem to be stopped properly and then interrupts my connection with devices connecting to the GATT Server.

The first thing I have tried was stopping and unbinding my BeaconScannerService, with the

```
beaconManager.unbind(this)
```

inside of the onUnbind() and OnStopService().

After this didn't work I tried to unbind the scanner right after finding my beacon:

```
override fun didRangeBeaconsInRegion(beacons: Collection<Beacon>, region: Region) {
        if (beacons.isNotEmpty()) {
            for (beacon in beacons) {
                if (!listOfBeacons.contains(beacon)) {
                    listOfBeacons.add(beacon)
                    sendNotificationFound()
                    localIntent.putExtra("BT_Address", beacon.bluetoothAddress)
                    localIntent.putExtra("Is_Connected", true)
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(localIntent)
                    Log.e("BEACON", "FOUND ONE " + beacon.bluetoothAddress)
                }
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "Stopping Service")
            beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)
            beaconManager.removeAllRangeNotifiers()
            beaconManager.stopMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region)
            beaconManager.removeAllMonitorNotifiers()
            beaconManager.unbind(this)
            beaconManager.isBound(this)
            stopSelf()
        }
    }
```

I have also enabled the debug option of the BeaconManager, but there is so much going on I have no idea what would be helpful.

In the end I would just like to be able to totally get rid of all beacon scanning after I have discovered my beacon.

Comment: What makes you think this statement is true?  "The problem is that the scan doesn't seem to be stopped properly and then interrupts my connection with devices connecting to the GATT Server".  The way you show stopping scanning should work.  Debug lines should confirm this.

Comment: The reason being this is printed when I call unbind()
**D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop: Stopping scan
D/CycledLeScanner: Destroying
D/ScanJob: Scanning stopped**

But then further down when I get:
**D/StartupBroadcastReceiver: onReceive called in startup broadcast receiver
D/StartupBroadcastReceiver: Passive background scan callback type: 1
    got Android O background scan via intent
D/ScanJobScheduler: Scheduling ScanJob to run every 300000 millis
D/ScanState: Scan state restore regions: monitored=0 ranged=0
I/CycledLeScanner: Using Android O scanner**

Answer (score 0):

A few points to clarify what's going on here:

- There are two ways to use the Android Beacon Library for background detections on Android 8+:  With scans initiated by the JobScheduler (default) and with an IntentService (only if you make a call to disable the default -- usually done in conjunction with a foreground service).
- When using the JobScheduler, scans run in the background approximately every 15 minutes as allowed by the operating system and does a low latency BLE scan to find all visible beacons.
- In between the 15 minute jobs, if no beacons are visible, the library will also set up an intent-based scan to wake up the library (and your app) to do an extra scan if any beacons appear.  This scan is not started if no regions are ranged or monitored.  If started, it is stopped at the beginning o the next job.
- The log line "got Android O background scan via intent" refers to getting a result from the type of scan in the point above.

**I suspect there is some library race condition that may leave this intent-based scan turned on in your specific case.  It might fix the problem to not call `unbind()`, and instead just stop ranging and monitoring as you have done.**

If that doesn't work, then if you attach a log excerpt from the time you try to stop the service to the time you get see "got Android O background scan via intent", I may be able to help track down the issue.  (Please also let me know the library version number you are using.)

Finally, I should add that I would be surprised if leaving this scan on really "then interrupts my connection with devices connecting to the GATT Server".  You may find that this is not the root cause of that problem.